# Abrir POST em arquivo php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Por padrão sei que posso listar alguns artigos wordpress em uma página externa em php usando um  **"require('../../wp-blog-header.php');"**.

Porém ao clicar em um desses artigos ele vai para página padrão que abre o Post completo.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Como faço para que o POSt completo seja aberto em um arquivo **(Ex. Postcompleto.php")** separado, ao invés de abrir na **single.php ?**

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o método de incluir `require('../../wp-blog-header.php');` para carregar qualquer conteúdo. O que muda é a forma como você chama o conteúdo dentro do seu arquivo externo.

Por padrão quando você incluir `wp-blog-header.php` ele vai carregar todo o back-end do WordPress com os parâmetros básicos, ou seja, ele carrega a página inicial. Daí pra frente ele vai obedecer o que estiver no seu arquivo, então você pode criar uma segunda query pra pegar o conteúdo que te interessa:

```
// Pra buscar um arquivo de posts do tipo "artigos"
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'artigos' /* etc */ ) );
if ( $query->has_posts() ) : 
    while ( $query->has_posts() ) : 
        $query->the_post();
        // exibe as informações aqui
    endwhile;
endif;
```

-

```
// Pra buscar um post pelo ID
$single = get_post( $id );
echo $single->post_title; // imprime o título
```

Agora, pra lincar de dentro do seu arquivo de posts para o php externo você provavelmente vai ter que filtrar as URLs que estão sendo exibidas. Algo assim é um caminho, mas existem outros dependendo do seu caso específico:

```
// em functions.php
add_filter( 'post_link', 'altera_link' ); // posts
add_filter( 'page_link', 'altera_link' ); // pages
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'altera_link' ); // custom post types
function altera_link( $link ) {
    // altera os links de 'example.com' para 'domain.com';
    return str_replace( 'example.com', 'domain.com', $link );
}
```

**mas: carregar `wp-blog-header.php` em geral é má ideia.**

Eu pensaria bem na arquitetura desse sistema porque existem jeitos melhores de não usar o sistema de templates do WP, se esse é o caso. Existem wrappers pra frameworks PHP (tipo [Corcel](https://github.com/corcel/corcel)), ou mesmo pra front-ends em javascript (tipo [NodeifyWP](https://github.com/10up/nodeifywp)) e existe o bom e velho Ajax pra puxar só o conteúdo que você quer.